# Qt open file with application to open that file in external application

Tags: linux, qt, desktop-application, code-editor

I am building a small application for Linux machines that allows you to select which editor you wish to open a file with. That is, set the default application for file types (such as .txt, .py, .java, etc.) to the application I am building. Then, the application gives a list of options for editors to choose from (currently VS Code and Atom). So far I have the application setup to allow the user the choose which application to launch and launch it. I have yet to implement opening a file in that editor. How may I go about completing this task?

Comment: i think you need to check command line parameters, for applications of you need to work. And execute this applications with parameters for opening file.

Comment: How could I pass parameters into the program?

Comment: The majority of applications that open files can be done from the terminal with the following command: `name_of_executable name_of_file`, and the above you can execute it through `QProcess`

Comment: But how can I pass parameters to the application I am building so I know the name of the file to open in the specified editor?